# I can't compile it with my Texstudio compiler!

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-calculate,textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(8,8)
\pstTriangle[PosAngle={180,90,0}](1,2){B}(2.5,5){C}(6,2){A}
\pstInterLC[PointSymbolB=none,PointName=none]{A}{C}{C}{B}{N}{N0}\uput[0](N){N}
\pstInterLC[PointSymbolB=none,PointName=none,Radius=\pstDistCalc{sqrt((2.5-1)^2+(5-2)^2)}]{B}{A}{A}{}{M}{M0}\uput[-90](M){M}
\psarc[origin={C}]{->}(C){0.5}{(B)}{(N)}\uput{5mm}[-10](C){75.9636\textdegree}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question 2:

When using PointNameB=none , it produces

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(3,4)
\pstTriangle[PointSymbolB=none,linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth](1.5,-1){A}(0,1){B}(-1,-.5){C}
\psset{PointNameB=none,PointSymbol=none}
\pstInterLC[PosAngle=45]{A}{B}{B}{C}{N}{N'}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When using PointNameB= , it produces normally

[image]

I don't know where the problem is, so if you know it please help me!

P/s: All files are be loaded with  latex->dvips->ps2pdf

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TBXtZSMDw8xNtN1qMFa_toXTmhXhfA9J/view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Click on the first Log button. Then you'll get antother one right of the first one. Click on
the right button and you'll get the latex original error message from the latex run. This is more helpful then the message from TeXstudio. BTW: I do not get any error message with up-to-date TeXLive

2) Use

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(3,4)
    \pstTriangle[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth](1.5,-1){A}(0,1){B}(-1,-.5){C}
    \pstInterLC[PointNameB=,PointSymbolB=none]{A}{B}{B}{C}{N}{N'}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have just edited your question with additional link. And with your code, I still get Dot style `none' not defined. :-(. You can help me to see it.

Comment: You should update your `pst-eucl.tex`:  http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-eucl/   This version is already uploaded to CTAN.

Comment: Yes, successful. Thanks. So " PointNameB= " replace " PointNameB=none " for \pstInterLC , unlike as the default, what is your idea?

Comment: that is really old code and will not changed for compatibility reason ...